# Using a SOAPHandler with spring-boot SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot

I have created an application by following the guide on
http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Executing the webservice 'getCountry' works fine but now I need to intercept the SOAP message somehow before getCountry is executed.

I created a class that implements 'SOAPHandler' but somehow I have to tell spring-boot to use this handler before passing the request to getCountry.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you need to do with the SOAP message? Spring offers an `EndpointInterceptor` interface along with some predefined implementations. You can specify which interceptors to use in the application context.

Comment: I need the SOAP message in order to extract the SAML token and do some custom checks with it.

Comment: Since I am using spring-boot there is no applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement an interceptor like:

```
public class YourClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor{

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext)
{

    //here you get your request before it is sending
    messageContext.getRequest() 

 ...

    return true;
}
```

}

and when you create your WebServiceTemplate you do:

```
ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = {new YourClientInterceptor ()};
yourWebServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```

They work similar with handler.